# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Live USB on HP ZBook 15 hangs while booting with kernel panic error: "A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value"

Tags: boot, kernel, hp, tpm

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB on HP ZBook 15/1909 hangs while booting with kernel panic error:

`A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value`

Previously installed Ubuntu 16.04 worked perfectly on the same system without any problems.

There is temporary workaround: Disable the TPM in the BIOS. This is however far from perfect solution.

Even installation and re-enable of the TPM in BIOS does not help.

Comment: Do you need TPM for Windows?

Comment: No, the system is single boot just to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Then it should be no problem to disable something that isn't supported anyway. That is the solution.